# Is there a CSS property to control or set the length of each side of a div

Tags: html, css, polygon

I've searched endlessly a way to control the length of each side of `div` in CSS. Just as you can control the color and width of each border. The aim is to create an irregular shape (Not square, not rectangle, perhaps a trapezium). I thought there could be something like

```
length-top:200px;
length-right: 150px;
length-bottom:300px;
length-left:100px;
```

If there's no way of doing that in CSS, what is the procedure to suggest augmentation of these properties?

Comment: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Have you seen, https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/#trapezoid-shape, from the site https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

Comment: I managed it with the `clip-path` property. Thanks @Aleksandar

Answer (score 0):

You should try this..

```css
div {    
  width:250px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid red;        
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.trapezium {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top-width:4px;
  border-bottom-width:1px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(150px) rotateX(40deg);    
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezium"></div>
```